# Limit of the ratio of positive and negative partial sums of $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{\sin n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ergodic-theory

Consider the series
$$S_N = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{\sin n}{n}$$

Let
$$S^{+}_{N} := \sum_{n=1}^{N} \max \left(\frac{\sin{n}}{n}, 0 \right) $$
$$S^{-}_{N} := \sum_{n=1}^{N} \min \left(\frac{\sin{n}}{n}, 0 \right) $$
i.e. $S^{+}_{N}, S^{-}_N$ are the partial sums of positive and negative elements of the sequence $\{ \frac{\sin n}{n} \}_{n \geq 1}$.

I want to study the following limit
$$\lim_{N \to +\infty}{\frac{S^{+}_N}{S^{-}_N}}$$

Intuitively it seems that the limit equals to $-1$, as the cardinality of the set of integers such that $\sin n > 0$ is "approximately equal" to the cardinality of the set of integers for which $\sin n < 0$, thus in the limit both parts give "the same" contribution.

Are there any hints to make the statement rigorous? Is there any way to utilize the Weyl equidistribution theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} S_N^{+}= +\infty$$
and $$\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} S_N$$ converges to a finite constant. Hence,
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty}  \frac{ S_N^{+}}{S_N^{-}}=\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty}  \frac{ S_N^{+}}{S_N- S_N^{+}} =\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty}  \frac{ 1}{ \frac{S_N}{S_N^+ }- 1 } = \frac{1}{0-1}=-1$$

Comment: Active as you are, why this first name ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh, you are up early. I chose my first name because I know deep down in me, I'm as lazy as my stupid cat :-)

Comment: Having followed your work on the site, the intelligence quotient of your cat is probably around $150+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm flattered by your compliment.

Comment: Indeed. No need for hard math with Weyl's theorem )